# Show Negative value for a particular field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a small set where when there is a row with '_Negative' then the final data should be '-data 1' only 
 (data2 will be always zero) .

if _Negative is not there then the 'Final data' should be sum(data1)-sum(data2)

[Actual Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT46b.png)

[image]

[Required value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opNxW.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
With
A as (select sum(data1)-sum(data2) as final_data 
      from your_table 
      where region1 not like '%_Negative'),
B as (select -data1 as final_data 
      from your_table 
      where region1 like '%_Negative')
Select your_table.*
  ,(case when region1 not like  '%_Negative' 
         then a.final_data 
         else b.final_data 
     end) final_data 
from your_table,a,b
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when region like '%_Negative'
             then data1 - data2
             else 0
        end) as final_data
from t;
```

Note:  This does not convert to an integer.  That seems to be desired based on the data but not based on the description of the problem.